# Repeat elements in preg_replace()

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace

I have string:`{$value.level-1.level-2.level-3 ... level-n}` and i need to change it to `{$value['level-1']['level-2']['level-3'] ... ['level-n']}`.

I now how to make only for one:

`preg_replace('(\{\$(.*?)\.(.*?)\})', '{$$1[\'$2\']}', $string);`
But how can i repeat it for all levels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need regex for this. For what you're trying to do, it's unnecessarily complicated, hard to read, and hard to maintain. Just use `str_replace` instead:

```
$leadinString = '$value'; // or '$test' or 'foobar' or whatever
$str = '{$value.level-1.level-2.level-3 ... level-n}';
echo str_replace(array("$leadinString.", '}', '.'), array($leadinString . "['", "']", "']['"), $str);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/tngIBI)

**Note:** I edited this based on your comment.

Comment: $value is only for question name, it can be $test or $user - so i need to user preg_replace

Comment: That wasn't clear from your question, but it's a pretty important point. That said, you can still use `str_replace`. See my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('#\.([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)#', '[\'$1\']', $string)
```

Comment: this regex replace everything from dot to end of file

Comment: Not sure why you included the underscore, nice answer anyway +1.

Comment: @l'L'l Because it can potentially be part of a property name. The philosophy of regex says that your pattern need to be as flexible as possible. If it works in one case, it's not said it will in another. I see a solution with str_replace has been chosen, which is very bad idea.